# How to aggregate on the same column?

Tags: database, oracle, aggregation

I am trying to figure out which seems very simple but I am not able to figure out a way to do same.

Consider following table and data,

```
create table dummy_query 
(id varchar2(20), amount number(10,2), memo varchar(20));

insert into dummy_query values('1', 10.00, 'Memo');

insert into dummy_query values('1', 20.00, 'Memo1');
```

I want to get the values as:

```
Id MemoValue  Memo1Value TotalSum

----------

1   10.00       20.00       30.00
```

Is there any way to get data in this manner?

Thanks!

Comment: Read up on PIVOT.  If memo has lots of possible values, then that complicates things.

Comment: Will there always be two rows per `id` with `memo` values of "Memo" and "Memo1"?  Or would you want to add a third column in the output if a third row was added to the table with an `id` of 1?  If you're using a recent version of Oracle and you want static output, you can use a simple `pivot`.  If you want the output to be dynamic, you'd have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks for quick responses. @JustinCave - There will be many values for memo but I'll be filtering only for 'Memo' & 'Memo1'. Also, there could be just one record say with Memo but not with 'Memo1' but there won't be more than two.

Comment: I am trying to understand Pivot and wrote this quick query, 
with t
as
(
select * from dummy_query
)
select * from T
pivot (
sum(amount) for (memo) in ('Memo','Memo1')
) 
Which works fine but how would I get the sume of Memo and Memo1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/828f5/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table dummy_query (id, amount, memo) AS
           SELECT '1', 10.00, 'Memo'  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL  SELECT '1', 20.00, 'Memo1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL  SELECT '1', 30.00, 'Memo2' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

If the `TotalSum` is the total of all memo amounts (and not just `Memo` and `Memo1`) then you can do:

```
SELECT ID,
       SUM( CASE memo WHEN 'Memo'  THEN amount END ) AS MemoValue,
       SUM( CASE memo WHEN 'Memo1' THEN amount END ) AS Memo1Value,
       SUM( amount ) AS TotalSum
FROM   dummy_query
GROUP BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/828f5/3/0)**:

```
| ID | MEMOVALUE | MEMO1VALUE | TOTALSUM |
|----|-----------|------------|----------|
|  1 |        10 |         20 |       60 |
```

**Query 2**:

But if the `TotalSum` is just `MemoValue + Memo1Value` then add in a where clause:

```
SELECT ID,
       SUM( CASE memo WHEN 'Memo'  THEN amount END ) AS MemoValue,
       SUM( CASE memo WHEN 'Memo1' THEN amount END ) AS Memo1Value,
       SUM( amount ) AS TotalSum
FROM   dummy_query
WHERE  memo IN ( 'Memo', 'Memo1' )
GROUP BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/828f5/3/1)**:

```
| ID | MEMOVALUE | MEMO1VALUE | TOTALSUM |
|----|-----------|------------|----------|
|  1 |        10 |         20 |       30 |
```

**Query 3**:

Or, if you need to include all rows for another reason, then you could do:

```
SELECT ID,
       SUM( CASE memo WHEN 'Memo'  THEN amount END ) AS MemoValue,
       SUM( CASE memo WHEN 'Memo1' THEN amount END ) AS Memo1Value,
       SUM( CASE WHEN memo IN ( 'Memo', 'Memo1' ) THEN amount END ) AS TotalSum
FROM   dummy_query
GROUP BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/828f5/3/2)**:

```
| ID | MEMOVALUE | MEMO1VALUE | TOTALSUM |
|----|-----------|------------|----------|
|  1 |        10 |         20 |       30 |
```

Comment: These queries are exactly what I was looking for and I like the fact that it works without use of pivot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Im not very familiar with PIVOT but what you have tried I did build query on that. Hope this is out put you need -

```
SELECT a.*, b.SUM_AMT
  FROM ((SELECT ID, amount, memo FROM dummy_query) PIVOT (SUM (amount)
                                                   FOR (memo)
                                                   IN ('Memo', 'Memo1'))) a,
       (  SELECT ID, SUM (AMOUNT) "SUM_AMT"
            FROM dummy_query
        GROUP BY id) b
 WHERE a.id = b.id
```

There can be better ways to reslove this so lets see what other folks have to share.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `pivot`, which you already started:

```
select id, memo, memo1, memo+memo1 msum from ( 
    select * from dummy_query 
    pivot (sum(amount) for (memo) in ('Memo' memo,'Memo1' memo1)))
```

and more traditional, without pivot:

```
select id, memo, memo1, memo1+memo msum from (
  select id, 
    sum(case when memo='Memo' then amount end) memo, 
    sum(case when memo='Memo1' then amount end) memo1
  from dummy_query group by id)
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5e33/3)</sup>